# Can I convert FILE* to FileInputStream/FileOutputStream in android-jni?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

**I've tried the code and it's feasible on Android.**

**Is there a simpler way?**

I hope it can be realized in a simpler and faster way

This is my code, I hope it can be realized more simply.

```
//C Lang Code

    FILE *file = fopen(path_utf, "w+");
     
    // native_fd

    fd = fileno(file);
```

```java
//Java

     final FileDescriptor mFd = new FileDescriptor();

     fd = native_fd;
     try {
          Field descriptorId = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("descriptor");
          descriptorId.setAccessible(true);
          descriptorId.setInt(mFd, fd);
     } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
     }

     new FileInputStream(mFd);

     new FileOutputStream(mFd);
```

Comment: What did you try? What is the problem? Any questions?

Comment: convert FILE* (c) to java I/O